# Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process' NextJS + Nightmare

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, next.js, puppeteer, nightmare

I'm trying to compile a simple example by using Next JS + Nightmare Scraper. However, when I try to access the page, I'm getting the error below, and the page does not load.

> PS C:\Users\lucas\Documents\Projects\ProjectTest\pages\nightmare> npm
> run dev
>
> Test@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\lucas\Documents\Projects\ProjectTest
> next dev
>
> ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
>
> event - compiled successfully
>
> event - build page: / wait  - compiling... error -
> ./node_modules/nightmare/lib/nightmare.js:17:0
>
> Module not found: Can't resolve 'child_process' null
>
> Could not find files for / in .next/build-manifest.json
>
> Could not find files for / in .next/build-manifest.json
>
> Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked,
> lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'

When I run by using node ./index.js, it works fine.

The same error occurs either using nightmare or puppeteer.

index.js

```
const test = require('nightmare');

function Page() {

    return <div>Test 2</div>
}

export default Page
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nightmare": "^3.0.2",
    "next": "^10.0.6",
    "puppeteer": "^7.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: You are saying you are getting a `nightmare` error when using `puppeteer`?

Comment: @MinusFour The same error happens either using nightmare or puppeteer.

Comment: Right... but the error is in `nightmare` source code. So if you are getting the same error, then you are still using `nightmare`.

Comment: PLease show more code because in this case it should be just the case were you didn't install dependencies. Did you do that with npm ?

Comment: This may be an indication that server-only code (Node.js environment) is trying to run on the client where `child_process` doesn't exist. We'll need additional code to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I've updated the question. The code is just as simple as this.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because when `nightmare` code (which expects to run on a Node.js environment) runs on the client `child_process` doesn't exist. You could add a condition to ensure it's only run on the server.

```js
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    const test = require('nightmare');
}
```

However, I'm unsure why you'd want to run it in a page. It's not meant to run in the browser.